# Why does my CSS not work as expected in Safari but it works fine on Chrome

Tags: html, css

I am making my own website and I wanted to test out a style for my photos where I essentially give them a colored shadow by placing an image with a blur effect behind the photo. It works great...on Chrome, Safari is another story.

Can someone explain why the image is shifted to the right on Safari but not on Chrome and how I can fix this?

Thanks!

**HTML**

```css
.center {
    text-align: center;
}

.focal-image {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
}

.focal-image-blur {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border-radius: 10%;
    -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
    filter: blur(10px);
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="center">
        <h1>Mark Reggiardo</h1>
        <p>Welcome to my website. This page is currently under construction. Meanwhile, here is a picture of the ocean :)</p>
        <img class="focal-image" src="/assets/images/CatalinaOcean.png" alt="A view of the ocean from my trip to Catalina Island">
        <img class="focal-image-blur" src="/assets/images/CatalinaOcean.png">
    </div>
</body>
```

**What the site looks like on Chrome:**

[image: Image and background blur appear as they should]

**What the site looks like on Safari:**

[image: Image is to the right of the background blur when it shouldn't be]

Comment: I grabbed your code examples and put them into codepen (but had to change the image) and in Safari 14.0.2 (Big Sur), I see the correct styling applied to the images. Could there be other code impacting this? Is your version of Safari or iOS dramatically different?

Comment: I don't think it's the version because it doesn't work on my iPhone either. Maybe there is other code affecting this, I'm not sure. Any ideas code and pixels?

Comment: When I remove the center class div it works fine on Safari. Guess I'll just have to try and center it some other way then

Comment: Well, here's the codepen I threw together: https://codepen.io/code-and-pixels/pen/VwmyyVJ. I removed the text from above the images and changed them out with images I could see/link to. I also commented out the height setting just because the new image wasn't square. But this works fine for me in Safari (macbook and iphone). Maybe check the centering or if there is other CSS related to images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem on Safari is that it does not align the imgs centrally, though Chrome uses the 'text-align: center' to do that.

A couple of adjustments to be made.

The absolutely positioned img needs to 'find' a parent element that is itself explicitly positioned. As the .center div is not, it goes back up and the positioning will  happen relative to the body (in the given snippet). So make the .center element have position: relative;

The main img is not getting centered correctly and to do that we can center it by first moving it 50% across the parent div and then back 50% of its own width.

Here's a snippet which works on both Chrome and Safari and you don't need to get rid of the .center div.

```css
.center {
    text-align: center;
    position:relative;
}

.focal-image {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    left:50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.focal-image-blur {
    width: 500px;  
    height: 500px;
    border-radius: 10%;
    -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
    filter: blur(10px);
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="center">
        <h1>Mark Reggiardo</h1>
        <p>Welcome to my website. This page is currently under construction. Meanwhile, here is a picture of the ocean :)</p>
        <img class="focal-image" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hk1uV.jpg" alt="A view of the ocean from my trip to Catalina Island">
        <img class="focal-image-blur" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hk1uV.jpg">
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you! I humbly bestow upon you the green checkmark, you have elegantly solved my problem!